# Progressive Table Rendering in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to make a table render progressively in Internet Explorer. It renders in Firefox progressively - however in IE. It renders it in memory so the table takes more time  to visibly appear.

I added a fixed-layout to the table, and set up a colgroup/col -

This is what the code looks like (I am constructing it in C# and utilizing bootstrap as well):

```
sb.Append("<table class='table table-condensed small table-hover table-bordered' style='table-layout: fixed;'>");
sb.Append(@"<colgroup span=13>
             <col width='350'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
             <col width='*'>
               </colgroup>");
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit on the purpose of your progressive tables so that it will help me to provide an appropriate solution? Thanks

Comment: Find an archaeologist :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do progressive HTML rendering with C# code. All your C# code will be executed before the page is even sent to the server.

Comment: I am talking about the progressive rendering of the table once it starts streaming to the web browser. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Yes, very clear. But alas, that's not happening. C# will not execute a bit, then stream to the server, execute a bit, stream more... No.

Answer (score 2):

Your html composition code will be executed on server and than composed html will be sent to your browser at once in response. The progressive rendering you see in Firefox is just an illusion, as the html response stream start and data flows to Firefox it starts rendering. However IE first completely validates html till closing tag of table and than renders it.

To do progressive html, you use dives instead of tables. It is more efficient approach and you will be able to get real benefit of bootstrap by making you design responsive.

If table is your only choice than you should specify the table-layout CSS attribute to achieve optimal performance out of Internet Explorer 5 or later. By doing the following, you'll allow Internet Explorer to start rendering the table before it has received all the data.

- Set the table-layout CSS attribute to fixed on the table.
- Explicitly define col objects for each column.
- Set the WIDTH attribute on each col.

See more details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533020(VS.85).aspx#Use_Fixed-Size_Tables

Comment: Does it do that in every situation? I have seen on quite a few occasions that a table is rendered progressively in Internet Explorer. I wonder if its because some of the initial columns are hidden that it causes it to happen.

Comment: You are right, you should specify the table-layout CSS attribute to achieve optimal performance out of Internet Explorer 5 or later. By doing the following, you'll allow Internet Explorer to start rendering the table before it has received all the data.
=> Set the table-layout CSS attribute to fixed on the table.
=> Explicitly define col objects for each column.
=> Set the WIDTH attribute on each col.
See more details at link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533020(VS.85).aspx#Use_Fixed-Size_Tables

Answer (score 0):

As IE renders the html block as whole the table will only be loaded when IE finished validating the enclosing tag as pointed out by Asad Mehmood. Rather use divs.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that it would be the table and not divs that could be rendered progressively. But if that is the ONLY option, then I should give you the bounty.

Comment: I believe in your situation it is, the divs will give you flexibility using bootstrap. But good luck man happy coding  :)